# Automatically fetch image from Google for WooCommerce product title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can we automatically fetch image from google as per the woocomemrce product title  and set it as product featured image?

Answer (score 0):

Image without copyright of course!

API Google
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list

Comment: I don't mind it being copyrighted because those are grocery items, Gentleman is there any plugin that can help with it? As I'm not a developer. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: No plugin does that to my knowledge, without dev, I don't see any solutions.
It's my pessimistic day :/